# android navigation component bottomnavigationview intercept click

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have a bottomnavigationview which is linked with navigation component using **setupWithNavController()**. It works as you would expect, pressing on the menu item will move me to a required window.

The problem is, that before redirecting to a different screen, I need to check if user is logged in or not and depending on that, I would need to redirect to a different screen.

So far it seems that I can use **setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()** on my bottomnavigationview, but then I loose all the convenience of **setupWithNavController()** as then I have to manually specify all the destinations I want to go.

Are there any better ways to implement this?

**Edit:** My login screen is actually transparent so, going to required fragment and then showing login screen on top might be tricky

Comment: There's guidance specifically around [how to do user login in Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#user_login).

Comment: Thanks for the link, Ian. I looked through it and it seems in my case this is not an option, because my login window is transparent (I updated the question) and if I first go to my menu fragment and only then show the login dialog user would be able to see not initialized window behind it. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

```
bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            if (//not login) {
                //to login fragment
                false
            } else {
                NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, homeController)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, that before redirecting to a different screen, I need
>   to check if a user is logged in or not and depending on that, I would
>   need to redirect to a different screen.

In this case, you can use `OnDestinationChangedListener` like this:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->

            if(destination.id == R.id.nav_profile && !isLoggedIn()){
                //Immediately pop the fragment
                controller.popBackStack()
                //Navigate to the login fragment
                controller.navigate(R.id.nav_login)
            }

        }
```

Here, the required fragment is removed from the back stack. And by this, you should not worry about transparent background of your login screen. Also, you won't lose any of the convenience of `setupWithNavController()`

However, you should make sure that the method `isLoggedIn()` is fast enough. Otherwise, a user might see the require function before it gets removed from the back stack.

Comment: have you used something like this before? Will I not have to worry about exceptions of fragments already being in progress like this?

Comment: I haven't used this before. And I think you shouldn't worry about exceptions of fragment process here as everything would be managed by Navigation Component.

Comment: @SMGhost if you are satisfied with the reply then please mark as answer.